# Iterate radio button in repeater using jQuery

Tags: jquery

net repeater in the below HTML. 
Outside repeater i have a button. on clicking of the button i want to iterate the and see if atleast one radio button is checked using jQuery.

Below is the html copied from inspect element.

```
 <div>
        <div class="row paddingtop110">

            <div class="column promo">
                <div class="balloon citrus">
                    <article>
                        <h3><span id="Span1" class="lbDurationDescripton">1 Month</span></h3>
                        <p>
                            <em>
                                <span id="ContentPlaceholder1_PricingTable_products_lblCancelText_0"></span>
                            </em>
                        </p>
                    </article>
                </div>
                <div id="ContentPlaceholder1_PricingTable_products_promoContainer_0" class="promo-container">


                    <div class="column-container">
                        <h6 style="display: initial"><strong id="lbPricePerMonth"><span>$8.99 for one month </span></strong></h6>
                        <ul>
                            <li><span id="lbDescription">$8.99 for one month</span></li>
                        </ul>
                        <footer class="button-area">
                            <div class="button-container">
                                <div class="shine"></div>
                                <span class="subscriptionRadio" name="radio1">
                                    **<input** id="ContentPlaceholder1_PricingTable_products_btnProduct_0" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceholder1$PricingTable$products$ctl00$Test" value="btnProduct"   class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"><label for="ContentPlaceholder1_PricingTable_products_btnProduct_0" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-left ui-button-text-icon-primary" role="button"><span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-radio-off">Select</span><span class="ui-button-text">Select</span></label></span>
                            </div>
                        </footer>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="column promo">
                <div class="balloon citrus">
                    <article>
                        <h3><span id="Span1" class="lbDurationDescripton">3 Months</span></h3>
                        <p>
                            <em>
                                <span id="ContentPlaceholder1_PricingTable_products_lblCancelText_1"></span>
                            </em>
                        </p>
                    </article>
                </div>
                <div id="ContentPlaceholder1_PricingTable_products_promoContainer_1" class="promo-container">


                    <div class="column-container">
                        <h6 style="display: initial"><strong id="lbPricePerMonth"><span>$21.99 for 3 months </span></strong></h6>
                        <ul>
                            <li><span id="lbDescription">$21.99 for 3 months</span></li>
                        </ul>
                        <footer class="button-area">
                            <div class="button-container">
                                <div class="shine"></div>
                                <span class="subscriptionRadio" name="radio1">
                                    **<input** id="ContentPlaceholder1_PricingTable_products_btnProduct_1" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceholder1$PricingTable$products$ctl01$Test" value="btnProduct" onclick="SetUniqueRadioButton(this);"  class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-icon-primary" role="button"><span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-radio-off">Select</span><span class="ui-button-text">Select</span></label></span>
                            </div>
                        </footer>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="column promo">
                <div class="balloon citrus">
                    <article>
                        <h3><span id="Span1" class="lbDurationDescripton">Year</span></h3>
                        <p>
                            <em>
                                <span id="ContentPlaceholder1_PricingTable_products_lblCancelText_2"></span>
                            </em>
                        </p>
                    </article>
                </div>
                <div id="ContentPlaceholder1_PricingTable_products_promoContainer_2" class="promo-container active">


                    <div class="column-container">
                        <h6 style="display: initial"><strong id="lbPricePerMonth"><span>$27.99 for 12 months </span></strong></h6>
                        <ul>
                            <li><span id="lbDescription">$27.99 for 6 months</span></li>
                        </ul>
                        <footer class="button-area">
                            <div class="button-container">
                                <div class="shine"></div>
                                <span class="subscriptionRadio" name="radio1">
                                    **<input** id="ContentPlaceholder1_PricingTable_products_btnProduct_2" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceholder1$PricingTable$products$ctl02$Test" value="btnProduct" onclick="SetUniqueRadioButton(this);"  class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-icon-primary ui-state-active" role="button" aria-pressed="true"><span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-radio-off ui-icon-radio-on"> Selected</span><span class="ui-button-text ui-icon-radio-on"> Selected</span></label></span>
                            </div>
                        </footer>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

     <input type="button" id="btnNext" onclick="reloadPage()" value="Next" />
```

On the button click i want to iterate the radio buttons and see if at least one is checked, if atleast one is checked then i want to redirect to another page or else stay in that page only.

I tried the below code

```
 function reloadPage() {

        $(".column-container").each(function () {

            if ($(this).find("input:radio").attr('checked')) {
                    alert('checked');
                }
                else {
                    alert('not checked');
                }
            });

    }
```

Eventhough i am checking one radiobutton at the below line i am always getting as undefined.
$(this).find("input:radio").attr('checked')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this : Instead of iterating all radio button and then check its status you can directly find the length of only checked radio button using `:checked` and if length is > 0 then atleast one radio button is checked.

```
function reloadPage() {
  var numberOfRadioBtnChecked =  $("div.column-container .button-area .button-container .subscriptionRadio input[type=radio]:checked").length;
   if(numberOfRadioBtnChecked > 0)
     alert('checked');
   else
     alert('not-checked'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could check the number of elements of a proper selector:

```
$(".column-container :input:radio:checked").length>0?console.log("redirect"):console.log("stay")
```

The code above checks whether there are any radio buttons checked within all containers who have `column-container` among their classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try the below sample code 

**HTML**

<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female<br>  
<input type="radio" name="status" value="yes">Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="status" value="no">No<br>
<button>Click</button> 

**JS**

$(document).ready(function() {
var checkedCount = 0;
$("button").click(function() {
    $("input:radio").each(function(index) {
        if ($(this).attr("checked") === "checked") {
            checkedCount++;
        }
    });
    //handle code if atleast one radio button is selected
    if (checkedCount > 0) {
        checkedCount = 0;
    }
});
```

});